# Export database table as .sql before deleting/removing a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, php

When you delete/remove a plugin all the database tables related to it will be deleted and I would like to know if there is a way to keep them or store them into a file and force the user to download it.

I made some kind of forum and saved many relevant information in a custom table but if someone deletes/removes the plugin accidentally or to include another row nothing will work anymore.

Is there I function I can use in `public function onBeforeUninstall()` to save my table?

I know you can go to phpmyadmin/adminer an use the export function by hand but we are all people and we can forget that.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your plugin overrides `onBeforeUninstall()`, then you could call `craft()->db->backup();`

But that will backup the whole database via PHP code, which might not be what you want.

Since you're in a plugin, I'd probably make sure [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) is available to PHP via the command line and use that to execute it and that way you can also specify the exact tables you'd like to dump.